# I have tried to Get info about redis queue like used_memory

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am trying to calculate metrics for a redis queue in c# using stackexchange.redis.

I need Info like used_memory.....etc

In redis.exe,Just INFO command gives all information..

How to get INFO details in c# using stackexchange.redis.

Answer (score 0):

use command `INFO  Memory` to show memory info only